# Browse to the tag synonyms page

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

How do I browse to the tag synonyms page of any Stack Exchange site? When I browse to the top-level Tags tab, I see only "popular" and "name" as sub-tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You can get to it from any individual tag synonym page:

[image: tag synonym page]